# No proper dense open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Let $U$ be a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, a positive integer, and suppose that $X:=\mathbb{R}^n-U$ is $0$-dimensional; in the sense of the [Lebesgue covering dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_covering_dimension).  Then is $U$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $U=\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: I think that if $U$ is not the whole $\mathbf R^n$, you should be able to argue that $\pi_{n-1}(U)$ is non-trivial (in fact, I think it should be possible to show that there is a ball around an element of $X$ whose boundary is disjoint from $X$).

Answer (score 0):

What about $$\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \lbrace (x,0), x \geq 0 \rbrace \quad \quad ?$$

Comment: Is it possible to construct a continuous map from $\mathbb{R}^2$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2 \ \{(x,0),x\geq 0\}$?

Comment: @Elbebe: Yes. It is easier if you think about $(-1,0)\times (-1,1)$ and $(-1,1)\times (-1,1)\setminus [0,1]\times \{0\}$. Define the homeomorphism separately for $y>0$ and analogously for $y<0$ (with identity for $y=0$). This can be easily seen to be equivalent.

Answer (score -2):

You are right.
Clearly, if $U=\mathbb{R}^n$, $U$ is a dense open subset of itself.

For the other implication, let us assume $\exists U\subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$, a dense open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $V:=\mathbb{R}-U$ $0$-dimensional. Since $V$ is $0$-dimensional, for any $\mathbf{y}\in V$, $B^n_{\epsilon}(\mathbf{y})\cap U\neq \emptyset,\;\forall \epsilon>0$ (Where $B^n_\epsilon(\mathbf{y})$ is $n$-dimensional ball, centered in $\mathbf{y}$ and radius $\epsilon$,).

Let, $$x_0\in \bigcap_{\epsilon >0} B^n_{\epsilon}(\mathbf{y})\cap U,$$
Then, since $U$ is an open set, the  $\exists\delta >0\;|\;B_{\delta}^n(\mathbf{x}_0)$ is contained in $U$. But, by construction, $\mathbf{y}\in B_{\delta}^n(\mathbf{x}_0)$, for any $\delta >0$. This is a contradiction, since we assumed $\mathbf{y}\notin U$.

Comment: This does not seem to make sense. I suppose you meant to write $y$ instead of $x$, but anyway, the intersection of these balls with $U$ is empty, since by hypothesis, $y$ is not in $U$.

Comment: @tomasz Yes, it $\mathbf{y}$. The intersectiom is not empty. If it was empty, then there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}^n(\mathbf{y})\cap U = \emptyset$, therefore, $B_{\epsilon}^n(\mathbf{y})\subseteq V$. Then, the messure of $V$ must be at least $Volume(B_{\epsilon}^n(\mathbf{y})) > 0$, but we assumed it was $0$.

Comment: Why would such $\epsilon$ exist? Look at it differently: if your argument worked, it would imply that there is no open proper subset of full measure, which is obviously false. You are not using zero-dimensionality, only density.

Comment: @tomasz I am saying there is no such $\epsilon$. What do you mean by full measure?

Comment: A subset of a measure space has full measure if the complement has zero measure. You claim that the existence of $\epsilon$ such that $B_\epsilon^n(y)\cap U=\emptyset$ follows from the emptiness of the intersection $\bigcap_{\epsilon>0}B_\epsilon^n(y)\cap U$. This is not true (unless $U$ is a compact set, which is not true).

Comment: @tomasz No, I said that, if the interesection was empty, then for some $\epsilon >0$, $B_{\epsilon}^n (\mathbf{y})\cap U =\emptyset$ (All bals are concentric, so they cannot have empty intersection). Since that leads to a contradiction (i.e. $V$ having non $0$ measure), then the intersection is not empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115937/discussion-between-jorge-and-tomasz).